# Store data from SQLite3 (win-rt) database in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, sqlite, scope, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a Windows Metro app using Visual Studio Express 2012 and an SQLite3-winrt database. My problem is that I can insert and read data from the database but I am unable to store any of the data that I have read in a local javascript variable.

```
function getInfo()
{   
    SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath)
    .then(function (db)
    {
        db.runAsync('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Resource (resourceName TEXT, resourceType TEXT, id INT PRIMARY KEY)')
        return db.eachAsync('SELECT * FROM Resource', function (row)
        {
            console.log('Get a ' + row.resourceName + ' for' + row.resourceType);
        });
 })

}
```

The above code works fine when data is inserted in the table but I cannot do something like this:

```
function getInfo()
{   
    var rName;
    SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath)
    .then(function (db)
    {
        db.runAsync('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item (resourceName TEXT, resourceType TEXT, id INT PRIMARY KEY)')
        return db.eachAsync('SELECT * FROM Resource', function (row)
        {
            console.log('Get a ' + row.resourceName + ' for' + row.resourceType);
            rName = row.resourceName;
        });
     })
return rName;
}
```

`rName` ends up being undefined even if I declare it as a global variable.

I suspect it has to do with the scope. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NB - I also tried returning `rName` at the line that says `rName = row.resourceName` but that also didn't work.

Comment: Your function returns `rName` immediately, before any of the async work is done. You need to return the set of async continuations to the caller.

Comment: can you give an example and show where the return statement is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SQLite installed, but in general you want to `return` the result of the nested `then` functions. Callers then use `then` to get the result. Something like:

```
function useResults()
{
  getInfo().then(function (rName) { console.log(rName); });
}

function getInfo()
{
  var rName;
  return SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath).then(function (db) {
    return db.runAsync('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item (resourceName TEXT, resourceType TEXT, id INT PRIMARY KEY)').then(function () {
      return db.eachAsync('SELECT * FROM Resource', function (row) {
        console.log('Get a ' + row.resourceName + ' for' + row.resourceType);
        rName = row.resourceName;
      }).then(function()
      {
        return rName;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Although this will only effectively return the last name.